# Uninstalling Android SDK Tools is stuck

Tags: android-studio, react-native, sdk, uninstallation

I've been having some trouble setting up my laptop for Android development with React Native. Various sources told me that uninstalling and reinstalling my SDK tools will fix the issue (the issue was that the **adb.exe** was missing thanks to AVAST)

When trying to uninstall my SDK tools the uninstaller is stuck:[image]

It's been saying `Stopping ADB` for at least 30 mins at the time of posting this and I cannot find other solutions for this.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Thanks.

I just need to be able to run my React Native apps in an Android virtual device.

---

Windows 10

Android Studio version 3.1.3

Comment: Hey, @Ryan, same happening to me now. Were you able to solve the issue?